# How to activate a background process using AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, process, windows-10, autohotkey, background-process

`mailmaster.exe` is running as a background process (not shown on the taskbar), I tried activating it (bring it to the foreground) using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> with the following script but didn't succeed:

```
!m::WinActivate ahk_exe mailmaster.exe
```

However, if `mailmaster.exe` is only minimized (still shown on the taskbar), I could bring it up with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

How to activate it if it's running as a background process (not shown on the taskbar) as well?

Comment: Try WinShow before WinActivate. See also DetectHiddenWindows.

Comment: @user3419297 Thanks, I tried `DetectHiddenWindows On` with `WinShow ahk_exe mailmaster.exe` and `WinActivate ahk_exe mailmaster.exe`, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mailmaster.exe` is a singleton app, the following code will do the job:

```
#IfWinNotActive ahk_exe mailmaster.exe
  !m::Run mailmaster
#IfWinNotActive
```

If the background app is not a singleton app, we could use the awesome [TrayIcon library](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=9186) to simulate a left click on the app's tray icon to show it up:

```
#IfWinNotActive ahk_exe mailmaster.exe
  !m::TrayIcon_Button("mailmaster.exe")
#IfWinNotActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [WinMaximize](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMaximize.htm) could help you

```
!m::WinMaximize, ahk_exe mailmaster.exe
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.